# UI5 sometimes throws error: Control with ID ... could not be found - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target

Tags: sapui5

Randomly, SAPUI5 throws error **Control with ID rootControl could not be found - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target** after login (SAP NetWeaver) to SAPUI5 page. I have tried to force an error login and logout. After many attempts (40 sometimes 102...), error occurred.

My root control is `<App id="rootControl">` in `App.view.xml`.

#### manifest.json

```json
{
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "id": "HomePage",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.6"
        },
        "ach": "CA-UI5-FST"
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "HomePage.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "rootControl"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.30",
            "libs": {
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {}
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                  "uri": "css/customStyle.css"
                }
            ]
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "HomePage.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "view": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
                "settings": {
                    "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                    "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                    "defaultCountMode": "None",
                    "useBatch": false
                }
            }
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "HomePage.view",
                "controlId": "rootControl",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "transition": "slide",
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": "notFound"
                },
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [{
                "pattern": ":Layout:",
                "name": "apphome",
                "target": "home"
            }, {
                "name": "id",
                "pattern": "Id/{Id}/:Layout:",
                "target": "id"
            }, {
                "name": "details",
                "pattern": "Details/{Details}/:Replace:",
                "target": "details"
            }],
            "targets": {
                "home": {
                    "viewId": "home",
                    "viewName": "Homepage",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewId": "notFound",
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "transition": "show"
                },
                "id": {
                    "viewId": "id",
                    "viewName": "Id",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "details": {
                    "viewId": "details",
                    "viewName": "Details",
                    "viewLevel": 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Randomly SAPUI5 throws error ...

I remember having the same issue due to the **race condition** in the past UI5 versions:

1. When starting the app, `Component.js` retrieves the root view asynchronously due to `sap.ui5/rootView/async: true`.
2. The `init` within `Component.js` usually initializes the router which retrieves the target view corresponding to the hash value **while** the root view is still loading.
3. Sometimes, the root view fails to be fully loaded prior to the target view which causes the error → target doesn't know where to put its view.

The [`commit:d054bc1`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d054bc161c0bac4e762c9e7c51e85ba59d1b2d43) makes sure that targets wait until the root view is fully loaded.
The fix was released with 1.54 but should be also available in 1.52.5+ according to the change log.
In order to see which UI5 version the app is running with, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Please upgrade the UI5 lib to the latest stable version.

I do **not** recommend to load the root view synchronously.

Comment: You have right. I am using UI5 lib version 1.44 :) I will change to a higher one.